# Possible to pipe a debug configuration through another command?

Tags: console, pipe, phpstorm

Using PHPStorm 6/7 (or WebStorm I guess), is it possible to configure a debug session so that it understands and uses piping to have a more convenient display in the PHPStorm console?  I'm working on a nodejs app that utilizes bunyan.  I'd like for PHPStorm to be able to pretty print the debug output as it would if I launched the app from the terminal.

Here's an example config:

[image: examle phpstorm debug config]

But the command it's trying to run is:

`/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=57073 app.js -vv 2>&1 "|" bunyan`

If it wouldn't quote the pipe symbol, it might work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Considering your end goal is to pipe your output through bunyan, you should take a look at [bunyan-prettystream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan-prettystream "bunyan-prettysteam").

Comment: Necromacing this question, to say thanks to Dustin. Now i can debug properly in Webstorm with pretty logs :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipes is a feature of the command line shell, PhpStorm doesn't use shell to start your configuration, so pipes and output redirection will not work.

Slightly related issues:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103907
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1933

You can probably hack some wrapper shell script around `node` and use it instead of the default `node` script. Your custom shell script can parse the arguments in its own way and perform piping. Not sure how well it will work.

Answer (score 4):

I found a bit a hacky solution for this problem that I also encountered. My solution doesn't include any configuration change in WebStorm. I simply created a piped output that is parsed with `bunyan` CLI tool which is loaded through node spawn `child_process`.

The code looks like this :

```
bunyan = require('bunyan');
logOptions = { name: 'myApp' };

// Activate this logger only for development and leave the original for production
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ) {
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    bunyanCLI = spawn('bunyan', ['--color'], { stdio: ['pipe', process.stdout] });
    logOptions.stream = bunyanCLI.stdin;
} 

log = bunyan.createLogger(logOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I used the code and I noticed that when node was exiting, some logs were not printing to stdout, presumable due to being piped to another process. I tried Shawn's module and it works for this case.

Answer (score 3):

I found better solution for logging buyan to the WebStorm console using the [bunyan-prettystream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan-prettystream)  package.

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
bunyan = require('bunyan');
logOptions = { name: 'myApp' };

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  var PrettyStream = require('bunyan-prettystream');
  var prettyStdOut = new PrettyStream();
  prettyStdOut.pipe(process.stdout);
  logOptions.stream = prettyStdOut;
}

log = bunyan.createLogger(logOptions);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm wrapping node into a shell script to achieve this.
This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

node $@ | ./node_modules/.bin/bunyan
```

You should never need to modify the code base in order to break-point debug in IDE.

To use it just modify your run configuration to use this script as `Node interpreter`.